# Logistic proof in TFL of a theorem

Tags: logic

[image]
This is supposed to be a hard one, I'm not sure what my beginning assumption should be. Should I assume -A and -B as two subproofs? The only hint here is this one uses IP rules (indirect proof)
With where to start it will be really helpful if you can teach me the main structure here! Thank you in advance

Comment: Use Excluded Middle

Comment: Just updated it with your hint, but got stuck in the middle, where should I go from here?

Comment: What is up with lines 8 and 9? Do you not have a rule of *reiteration* (or *restatement*)?

Comment: It is an easy task, applying $\lor$-elim to $A \lor \lnot A$. From case (i) $A$ we have immediately $(B \to A)$ and the final result. From case (ii) $\lnot A$ we assume $A$ and derive $B$ followed by $(A \to B)$, discharging assumption $A$, and again we have the result.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

Your aim is to derive a contradiction under the first assumption.   So far you have derived $\lnot(A\to B)$.   That is not a bad start.

Consider that if the assumption really is inconsistent, you should also be able to derive $A\to B$.   A conditional proof would be required for this.

Now there are two ways you could derive $B$ under assumption of $A$: either directly or through the principle of explosion (also called 'ex falso quodlibet', or 'contradiction elimination').   Well, you have nothing that would directly derive it, so you must try the second option.

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{~~1.~\lnot((A\to B)\lor(B\to A)}{\fitch{~~2.~A\to B}{~~3.~(A\to B)\lor(B\to A)\\~~4.~\bot}\\~~5.~\lnot(A\to B)\\\fitch{~~6.~A}{~~~~\vdots\\~~~~.~~\bot\\~~~~.~ B}\\~~~~.~A\to B\\~~~~.~\bot}\\~~~~.~(A\to B)\lor(B\to A)}$$

Once you have filled out the missing detail, it should become evident that you can rearrange things for a more elegant proof.

---

Hint:

> $A\to(B\to A)$ is a tautology.

Comment: I just updated my solution, I am a bit lost after line 11 please correct me, i think I'm not on the right track

Comment: You just need more closure. At 12 the inference should be $A$ by *explosion*, so you may close the 'second floor' subproof to deduce $B\to A$ by *conditional introduction*; and then you can infer $(A\to B)\lor(B\to A)$ by *disjunction introduction* on the 'first floor'.

Comment: I can conclude -B on line 12, but I wan not taught of the explosion method, and I don't think it is a rule here? I am really confused how you can get to B->A here

Comment: @n.y Explosion, or *ex falso quodlibet*, is the rule that anything may be derived from a contradiction. If you do not have access to this (although you should), you may use an Indirect Proof. $$\begin{array}{|l}\mathrm m.~~\bot\\\mathrm n.~~\phi\qquad\textsf{X }\mathrm n\end{array}\qquad\begin{array}{|l}\mathrm m.~~\bot\\\begin{array}{|l}\mathrm n.~~\lnot\phi\\\hline\mathrm o.~~\bot\qquad\textsf{R }\mathrm m\end{array}\\\mathrm p.~~\phi\qquad\textsf{IP }\mathrm{n{-}o}\end{array}$$

Comment: Finally got it, thank you so much!